# How do you say "I made books fall off the shelf"

Tags: word-usage, idiom-requests

One way is to say "I spilled the books off the shelf". I am looking for a more suitable usage of words.

Comment: *In a fit of rage, deciding the books were placed improperly on the shelf, I acted, leaving the books sprawled across the floor.*

Answer (score 6):

I knocked the books off the shelf.

Answer (score 2):

I toppled the books off the shelf.